# Repairing a nail pop near a vent, unsure if it's safe to repair due to voltage detector (blue/red) and resistance when attempting to drill

Tags: drywall, repair, ceiling

Attempting to repair a nail (or screw? unsure) pop in some angled ceiling (creates a V like vault shape), the nail pop are near a vent for the AC (in the ceiling). Two nail pops in vicinity of each other (probably 2 ft), approximately parallel to each other as well.

Noticed that my voltage detector would go blue (klein voltage detector) when near the vent and red if I pressed it right up against the vent as tight as possible. The voltage detector is generally, but not always, blue near the popped nails and the space between as well.

Basically the vent is between the two pops, though the popped dry wall is spaced a bit farther from the vent. The popped locations never go red, but they do trigger blue sometimes.

The voltage detector appears to works on live things, like sockets and cords (red). It doesn't seem to trigger easily if I just try to rub my hand with it (no blue or red). I tried another ceiling vent and it doesn't trigger no matter how I rub it against the vent. It did trigger on a floor vent in the same room though. The AC was on during all these tests, if that matters.

I tried to put a dry wall screw parallel to the other two screws similar to youtube guides I saw but it actually seems to be nothing is there. Having fixed some holes in the house in similar locations.. for whatever reason the beams are not parallel to the wall and will just give you nothing (drills into dry wall and nothing else). But perpendicular to the wall works, so screwing closer to the wall and further from the wall in line with the screw. Given that I attempted to go perpendicular to the wall further and closer to the wall near this vent, I received some resistance where the screws appeared to twist in place (rather than going deeper). Since I know screw / nail plates existed I was nervous and stopped.

Now I am not sure what to do or if it's safe to continue to work on though. If I can't screw parallel to the wall, in the line of the screws, and perpendicular to the wall appears to be plate / a vent that can trigger red on the voltage detector..

Just hoping someone might have some info to help this situation. I watched some youtube videos, and read some posts about nail plates (in regards to my issue), but beyond that I am a flying blind / very novice.

I do have another location I have concerns about, but it doesn't report any voltage from the detector. The issue for that one is that I have to be perpendicular to the nail to have it not drill straight through the dry wall (as described above), but then there is clearly some sort of plate on other side of the nail as there is very obvious 'spinning in place'. Seems to be another spot I am unsure how the heck it was attached to the ceiling in the first place if there is a plate there and yet the ceiling is popping.

Thank you for any tips or guidance.

Comment: The working AC might cause enough static electricity, but should not when not working.  Nail plates should not spin.  Wires if any near the ceiling should go up/down, seldom do they go horizontally near the ceiling, unless there are two high wall lights.

Comment: Sorry I mean the nails spin in place, nothing appears to spin behind the wall. Just stops and I don't want to 'ram' the nail into whatever is stopping it. I had a few successful ones where it was clearly sinking into wood and the nail head going a bit through the dry wall to hold it into place (and make clean up look good), so I think I have a reference of what it is supposed to feel / look like. These ones didn't go all the way down/through and just spun, different than being put through dry wall and nothing behind as the screw hasn't even gone all the way through yet.

Comment: Screws are usually used these days since they tend to hold better.  Wires/cables are suppose to be at least an 1.5 inches from the edge of the wood or need nail plates.  Can try to pull the nail/screw out and move it an inch or two.  They might have hit the edge and split the wood(very minor).